# Which controls are performed before downloading a signed-applet?

Tags: java, certificate, signed-applet

**The problem:**

I'm working on a legacy project (with unreliable documentation) featuring some signed-applets, compiled with a specific jdk (1.6.0_45) that's been handed down from dev to dev along with the project.

Recently, I've had to make a minor modification on those applets, and while the newly compiled and signed version works like a charm on our company's computers, they refuse to load on the users' machines, which have stricter security rules.

The error message we're getting is the following:

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

It's worth noting that, on an other server, an unmodified version of those applets runs perfectly fine, so the error is definitely on my side, not on the users'.

What could be the security rules that are blocking those applets on the users' machine? What can I do to give those applets proper clearance?

**Additional info**

the server that hosts the project runs an Apache and a Tomcat instance, Tomcat serving most of the website, but Apache being apparently required to serve the applets.

I've checked the Tomcat's TrustKeystore, which appears up to date with the user's private certificates. I don't know where I can perform a similar check on the Apache side of the server.
I also don't know where the users' specific security rules are defined. I checked their java "security" folder, but everything in it is default.

**Edit:**

I've used the jarsigner utility to check the signatures on the jar, and while the ones I've updated, the ones that don't work, have valid current certificates, the ones I've left alone, that still function, have expired certificates.
Would it be possible that the user is working with outdated certificates, getting an OK on the expired signatures of the old applets, but blocking on the up-to-date ones? How can I check that?

Comment: step 1: reconsider using applets. just because your company decides using versions of browsers that will fail any decent security test, doesn't mean you should, nor that your clients will. applets are no longer supported by modern browsers.

Comment: Getting completely rid of applets is definitely on the menu for the near future. But until that' done, we still need them to function.

Comment: that's the point. Unless you within your company are the only ones to use that application, you can't guarantee they work.